# C# Generics - Lists of collections

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a hierarchy of classes based on an abstract `Device` class. The repository of all devices looks a bit like this:

```
class Hardware
{
    public readonly DeviceCollection<Switch> Switches = ...;
    public readonly DeviceCollection<Light> Lights = ...;
}
```

where `DeviceCollection` implements `IEnumerable<T> where T : Device`.

I need to enumerate across all devices, and my currently crappy code does this

```
    protected override IEnumerator<Device> enumerate()
    {
        foreach (var light in Lights)
        {
            yield return light;
        }

        foreach (var @switch in Switches)
        {
            yield return @switch;
        }
    }
```

This is not robust as sometimes I add a new bit of hardware, a new `DeviceCollection` and it's easy to forget to add a new iteration in the above. So I figured a bit of reflection would help - lazily build a list of the `DeviceCollection` fields and run through that. But what would the declaration of that list look like?

```
private List<DeviceCollection<T>> _collections;
```

doesn't compile. Neither does

```
private List<DeviceCollection> _collections;
```

How do I declare this list?

---

Corollary: Tim S's answer - that IEnumerable is covariant - solves my immediate problem. One little glitch left (which I'm sure has a simpler solution!) is how to do the reflection. Here is my ugly ugly ugly hack:

```
_collections = new List<IEnumerable<Device>>();
var fields = GetType().GetFields( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public );
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    if (field.FieldType.Name.Contains( "DeviceCollection" ))
    {
        _collections.Add( (IEnumerable<Device>)field.GetValue(this) );
    }
}
```

This, because the test

```
if (field.FieldType == typeof(DeviceCollection<>)
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use multiple collections as separate fields but a single dictionary with a `DeviceType` enum as key.

Comment: I think your "crappy" code is perfectly reasonable, and probably the best solution.

Comment: `typeof(IEnumerable<Device>).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType)` can handle your corollary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The declaration would be:

```
private List<IEnumerable<Device>> _collections;
```

And you could use it (after setting it up, which you already seem to have a good idea how to do) as easily as:

```
protected override IEnumerator<Device> enumerate()
{
    return _collections.SelectMany(x => x).GetEnumerator();
}
```

This works because the `IEnumerable<T>` interface is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx), meaning that, e.g. an `IEnumerable<Switch>` (which `DeviceCollection<Switch>` implements) can be used as an `IEnumerable<Device>`.

The reason that a `DeviceCollection<Switch>` can't be used as an `DeviceCollection<Device>` is that classes and collections can't be covariant - it wouldn't make sense to let you try to `Add` a `Device` to an `ICollection<Switch>`, because it should only contain `Switch`es. But it makes perfect sense to get a `Device` out of an `IEnumerable<Switch>`.

Answer (score 2):

I would contend that you just need a single list:

```
public DeviceCollection<Device> Devices { get; private set; }
```

and then you can return specific types with `Switches` for example:

```
public IEnumerable<Switch> Switches
{
    get
    {
        return this.Devices.OfType<Switch>();
    }
}
```

and so now `enumerate` just looks like this:

```
protected override IEnumerator<Device> enumerate()
{
    foreach (var d in Devices)
    {
        yield return d;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `OfType` will try to find `Switch` type, but the `Devices` is a list of `DeviceCollection<T>`. You need a `SelectMany` in there. Or change `Device` to be a `List<Device>`, simply.

Comment: @SimonBelanger, actually `Devices` is a list of `DeviceCollection<Device>` which is the base class for all objects placed in the list. It would be like adding to the `Controls` collection and then using `OfType<TextBox>` to get all text boxes.

Comment: I get that. I used `T` as the base definition. `Devices` has no element of type `Switch`. It has an element (or many) of type `DeviceCollection<Switch>`. Your code will yield an empty list.

Comment: @SimonBelanger, I think I know what you're saying now. I see the failure in the definition. See my edit.

Comment: So what happens when someone adds a Switch to the DeviceCollection<Switch> at HardwareInstance.Switches? Since that collection is transient and has no relationship to the underlying Devices collection, the new Switch isn't added to HardwareIntance.Devices and effectively disappears. This is a very dangerous solution.

Comment: -1 This creates a *new* `DeviceCollection<Switch>` every time you call the `Switches` property.  Maybe that's fine but it has different semantics than OP's code and could break things.

Comment: If you change `Switches`'s type to `IEnumerable<Switch>` you could solve that problem.

Comment: @DaxFohl, as Tim stated, it could easily just be used as an `IEnumerable` so I modified it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it:

```
private List<DeviceCollection<Device>> _collections;
```

Comment: You'd think. But the case from DeviceCollection<Switch> to DeviceCollection<Device> fails.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a member variable?  I'd think you could do

```
protected override IEnumerable<Device> enumerate()
{
    ... reflect to get properties of type IEnumerable<Device>
    foreach (var prop in properties) 
    {
        foreach (var device in (IEnumerable<Device>)prop.GetValue(this))
        {
            yield return device;
        }
    }
}
```

Per the comments on efficiency, while I disagree with them, and also disagree with the solutions that propose using a single `List` and `OfType`, if reflection is too slow/dangerous, you could simplify your original code:

```
public IEnumerable<Device> GetAll() {
    return from list in new IEnumerable<Device>[] {Switches, Lights}
           from device in list
           select device;
}
```

Comment: @Moo-Juice because that's what OP asked for in the question

Comment: Ah, my bad.  It just like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly.

Comment: @DaxFohl Well, let's say for a second that it is indeed an option (although  terribly inefficient). You are assuming that that all public properties implements `IEnumerable<Device>`. You should at the very least filter out your property.

Comment: @SimonBelanger I get that.  Personally I think OP's original solution is the best option.  I'm just answering his question.